# Getting rid of stopwords for text-mining excercise

Tags: python

I have the following code following a tutorial to be found here: http://blog.christianperone.com/2011/09/machine-learning-text-feature-extraction-tf-idf-part-i/:

```
train_set = ("The sky is blue.", "The sun is bright.")
test_set = ("The sun in the sky is bright.",
        "We can see the shining sun, the bright sun.")

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

print(vectorizer)
#CountVectorizer(analyzer__min_n=1, analyzer__stop_words=set(['all']))
vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set)
print(vectorizer.vocabulary)

smatrix = vectorizer.transform(test_set)
print(smatrix.todense())
```

This gives me a matrix of words used in the different sentences. This works fine howver I would like to get rid of some stopwords.

Therefore I try:

```
CountVectorizer(analyzer__min_n=1, analyzer__stop_words=set(['is', 'the']))
```

This however gives me the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Marc/PycharmProjects/clustering/testing.py", line 16, in  <module>
CountVectorizer(analyzer__min_n=1, analyzer__stop_words=set(['is', 'the']))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'analyzer__min_n'
```

Any thoughts where this goes wrong

Comment: According to the docs, `analyzer__min_n` does not exist: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

Comment: @Avión: its mentioned here: http://blog.christianperone.com/2011/09/machine-learning-text-feature-extraction-tf-idf-part-i/

Comment: Try this: `CountVectorizer(stop_words=(['is', 'the']))`

Comment: No this does not change the ouput...smatrix output stays the same